# How to keep one class active at a time in Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently working on an donation form for a client and am having some issues with the buttons. As shown below:

when I click on that input box it gives the correct background color but if I type something in to it and delete that value the background color will stay and toggle back to the default value of 50. I want to input box to ALWAYS be the only one active if the text curser is there. Even if a user deleted what they type and the curser is still there I want the input box to be the only one with that background color while it shows it's active.

[image]

so if I just click on it it will be the only one active but when I type something into it and delete it it will remain active but also toggle the default of $50 so two will be active at one time.
    [image]

here is my jquery:

```
var defaultValue = 50; 

$(document).ready(function() {

$('#donation-amount').keyup(function() {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');

      if($(this).val()) {
         $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
    } else {
       $('#display-amount').text(defaultValue);
       $("#default").addClass('active');
       $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
       $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
    }
});

     $( ".selectvalue" ).click(function() {
        $('#display-amount').text($(this).val());
     });

    $(".buttons .btn").click(function(){
        $(".buttons .btn").removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active'); 
      $('#donation-amount').css("background-color","") 
    });
$("#donation-amount").click(function() {

         if ($(this).hasClass('inpt-first')) {
             $(this).css("background-color", "#c97e06");
             $("#default").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn2").removeClass('active');
             $("#btn3").removeClass('active');
            $('#display-amount').text('--');
         } 

        else{
            $("#default").addClass('active');   

        }

    });
$('#donation-amount').blur(function() {
  $(this).attr('style', '');
  if($(this).val() == null || $(this).val() == 'Custom') {
    $('#default').addClass('active');
    $('#display-amount').text(50);
  }
});

    $('#display-amount').text($('#default').val());

});
```

here is my html:

```
<div class="form-container">
<div class="donate-heading text-center">
  <h1>Donate Now!</h1>
</div>
<div class="form-content">

<form action="" method="POST" id="payment-form">
  <span class="payment-errors"></span>

  <div class="content-inner">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <fieldset>
        <legend class="text-center">How much would you like to donate</legend>
        <div class="choose-pricing">
          <div class="btn-group">
          <div class="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="default" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color active" value="50">50</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="100">100</button>
            <button type="button" id="btn3" class="btn btn-default selectvalue hover-color" value="150">150</button>
            <input type="Custom" name="donation-amount" class="inpt-first form-control" id="donation-amount" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="Custom">
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="donation-amount-value" id="donation-amount-value">
          </div>
          <div class="money-donate">
            <div class="display-amount" id="display-amount">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </div>
  <legend class="text-center">Enter your card details</legend>
  <span class="full">Enter yor 16 digit card number:</span>
  <div class="credit-card-num">
    <input type="text" name="cardNumber" id="creditCardNumber" onclick="if(this.defaultValue == this.value) this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = this.defaultValue" value="XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" data-stripe="number">
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">
  <div class="date-wrapper">
    <div class="month">
      <span class="full">Month & Year of Expiry:</span>
      <select name="month" id="expMonth" class="selectBox chzn-done" data-stripe="exp-month">
        <option data-stripe="cvc">Select Month</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
      <div id="expMonth_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1">
        </a>
      </div>
      <select name="year" id="expYear" class="selectBox chzn-done" data-stripe="exp-year">
        <option value="">Select Year</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="cvn">
      <span class="full">Card Verrification Number
        <a href="#" class="tooltip">
          <img src="/wp-content/themes/creativeforces/images/question.png" alt="question">
        </a>
        <div class="tooltip-hover">
          <img src="" alt="">
        </div>
      </span>
      <input type="password" name="cardVeriNum" id="cardVeriNum">
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="personal-detail">
    <legend class="text-center">Personal Details</legend>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First Name">
        <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>
    </div>
       <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <!-- <textarea name="address" class="form-control" id="address">Address</textarea> -->
        <textarea name="notes" class="form-control" id="add-note" placeholder="Additional Notes"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group button">
      <div class="text-center">
      <button id="donate-btn" value="Donate" class="btn btn-default">Donate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
  </div>
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you make it fiddle link?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/os1r1z9h/

I can't get my jquery to work on it though

Comment: For your Fiddle, it helps if you include the jQuery library and put the JavaScript code in the designated JavaScript area (instead of in the CSS area): https://jsfiddle.net/qhn8ht7f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making the `#default` become active when the value is empty, but the cursor is there, you don't need that line.

Comment this line `$("#default").addClass('active');` inside your `else` inside `$('#donation-amount').keyup(function()`.

---

This will reset the value inside `.donation-amount` when another button is clicked.

Add this line `$('.donation-amount').val("");` inside the `if` inside `$("#donation-amount").click(function()`.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/va9nmr3g/

Comment if you have any questions